# Unable to use NGINX as a WebSocket proxy for WebSocket server setup with php React and Rachet

Tags: php, nginx, websocket, ubuntu-18.04

All of below is running on Ubuntu 18.04

I want to use nginx as a WebSocket proxy for a websocket server that I'm running using a combination of Php's React and Rachet WebSocket.

I have the php implementation as follows:

```
$app = new Chat();
$socket = new React\Socket\SecureServer('192.168.10.11:6001', $loop);
$ws = new Ratchet\WebSocket\WsServer($app);
$wss = new Ratchet\Server\IoServer(new Ratchet\Http\HttpServer($ws), $socket, $loop);
```

I largely follow [this guide](https://www.nginx.com/blog/websocket-nginx/) to set up the nginx server block:

```
map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
    default upgrade;
    ''      close;
}

upstream websocket {
    server 192.168.10.11:6001;
}

server {
    listen 6002;
    server_name mydomain.com;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://websocket;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
    }
}
```

I restart nginx with an 'OK' status and try to wscat my websocket server using the proxy:

```
node_modules/wscat/bin/wscat --connect ws://mydomain.com:6002
error: Unexpected server response: 504
```

I am, however, able to wscat the websocket server directly, so I know it's working properly

```
node_modules/wscat/bin/wscat --connect ws://mydomain.com:6001
Connected (press CTRL+C to quit)
```

I would like to be able to set up a connection with this websocket server using the NGINX proxy. What am I missing? Is it something to do with the websocket server in the php implementation?

I have opened port 6002.